# How to use "self" to access a custom property of a specific bone and/or object?

Tags: drivers

I'm looking for guidance on referencing custom properties in driver's using self.

The biggest thing I'm struggling with is syntax.
The following don't work.

Where prop is the name of a custom property, the following do not work in the expression field:

```
self.prop
self[prop]
self.[prop]
self["prop"]
self.["prop"]
```

Any ideas how to use self in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For custom property, `self["prop"]` is correct.

Make sure that use self is active:

[image]

and property is located in Object data / Bone data